# Disable datatables when processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm using datatables with processing message but I would like to block datatable when this message show up. This is important because otherwise the user may use an old row.
This is my configuration:

```
datatableTable = $('#datatableTable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            deferRender:    true,
            scrollY:        '60vh',
            scrollCollapse: true,
            scroller:       true,
            "bProcessing": true,
```

and I'm using this message css:

```
div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_processing {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-top: -26px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Is there a way to block datatable? thanks

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "block datatable"? Disabling datatable control elements such as pagination and column headers or something else?

Comment: In each row of my datatable I have several buttons, files browse and so forth, I would like to forbid the use of these element.

Comment: Then it has no relation to datatables. Since you output your input elements inside table yourself, you have to disable them yourself too. Datatables can't do all work for you.

Comment: Isn't it possible to disable the entire datatable? I see that all the commands given during processing are elaborated at the end of elaboration (even the columns ordering)

Comment: No way except manual disabling all child input elements (e.g. using loops).

Comment: I hoped there was a datatables built in function

Comment: or you can do it by create new `div` element with fixed position width 100% and height 100%, `top 0px` and `left 0px` with transparent background. and z index above you page.
set it by default to `display:none`

and then set it to `display:block`when you want to disable all function when processing something.

after the process done, just hide it back

Answer (score 1):

You can just disable mouse interaction:

```
$("body").addClass("disabled");
```

And css:

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

You can also put a fixed overlay between your message and body and set some opacity (like 0.5), black background, proper z-index etc. to make it hide everything that is behind.

Maybe you should also read something about database's transactions - there're a solution for many problems with data.

Comment: I already have my modal to disable all page, I was only wondering if was possibile to disable only the table

Comment: Of course - you can add id for your table (for example #tableid) and write:

Comment: `$("#tableid").addClass("disabled");` :)

Comment: I have the same issue, Is there any way to freeze the pagination button when the datatable is processing?